# ASP.net Core Controller added or modified later on during runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have a generic controller which is initialized for custom types on startup. I'd like to implement a functionality to add, refresh and drop these controllers later on. (All 5 minutes, on an API-call, ...) How is this possible? The new types are delivered by the IExternalCompiler

```
public class ExternalControllerFeatureProvider : IApplicationFeatureProvider<ControllerFeature>
{
    private readonly IExternalCompiler _entityCompiler;

    public ExternalControllerFeatureProvider(IExternalCompiler entityCompiler)
    {
        _entityCompiler = entityCompiler;
    }

    public void PopulateFeature(IEnumerable<ApplicationPart> parts, ControllerFeature feature)
    {
        foreach (var candidate in _entityCompiler.GetTypes())
        {
            feature.Controllers.Add(
                typeof(GenericController<>).MakeGenericType(candidate).GetTypeInfo()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

This IApplicationFeatureProvider is added in Startup.Configure to the ApplicationPartManager